# Adding a Variable to QuerySet in Django at Runtime

Tags: django, django-models

I have a method that gets the difference between a value on a model and a value stored in `request.session`. I can attach the method to the model as model method but I can't pass `request` to it from a template, so that's a no go! Can I somehow attached a value to a model queryset at runtime and then populate it in `view.py` with the result of the calculation?

Comment: I'm not quite following. Can you provide some example code?

Comment: I found my answers in the docs

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I was missing was [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) *(Django > built-in templates > timesince)*